# Change drawn rectangles (in barchart) based on the text in a combo box? VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, graph, combobox, drawing

I'm trying to make a program that displays the results of students in miniature tests and I'm trying to make it so that the teachers can see barcharts of the average scores that the students in a particular class get. However, I want to be able to switch classes via a combobox and would like the barcharts to change to the correct barchart when the class is changed.

Here is the code for that particular part:

```
Private Sub TMenu_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    dbProvider = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;"
    dbSource = "Data Source=Database.mdb"

    con.ConnectionString = dbProvider & dbSource

    con.Open()

    sql = "SELECT GroupID FROM Class ORDER BY GroupID ASC"
    da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con)
    da.Fill(ds, "Class")
    maxrows = ds.Tables("Class").Rows.Count

    For index = 0 To maxrows - 1
        cmbclass.Items.Add(ds.Tables("Class").Rows(index).Item(0))
    Next

    cmbclass.Text = "Group1"

    Call DrawGraph()

End Sub

Private Sub cmbclass_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmbclass.SelectedIndexChanged

    lstSUsername.Items.Clear()
    sql2 = "SELECT Student.SUsername FROM Student WHERE SClass= '" & cmbclass.Text & "'"
    da2 = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql2, con)
    ds2.Clear()
    da2.Fill(ds2, "Student")

    maxrows2 = ds2.Tables("Student").Rows.Count

    For index = 0 To maxrows2 - 1
        lstSUsername.Items.Add(ds2.Tables("Student").Rows(index).Item(0))
    Next

    draw_options = 0
    Me.Invalidate()
    Call DrawGraph()
End Sub
Sub DrawGraph()
    topic(1) = "Binary to Denary"
    topic(2) = "Denary to Binary"
    topic(3) = "Hexadecimal to Denary"
    topic(4) = "Denary to Hexadecimal"
    topic(5) = "Binary to Hexadecimal"
    topic(6) = "Hexadecimal to Binary"
    topic(7) = "Reverse Polish Notation"
    topic(8) = "Binary Normalisation"

    'Extract data for graph
    'For each topic...
    For i = 1 To 8
        'Find the test marks for a specific topic for the selected group
        sql4 = "SELECT Test.Mark FROM Test, Student WHERE Student.SUsername = Test.SUsername AND Test.Topic = '" & topic(i) & "' AND Student.SClass = '" & cmbclass.Text & "'"
        da4 = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql4, con)
        ds4.Clear()
        da4.Fill(ds4, "Testmarks")
        'Find the number of records
        maxrows4 = ds4.Tables("Testmarks").Rows.Count
        total = 0
        For count = 0 To maxrows4 - 1
            total = total + ds4.Tables("Testmarks").Rows(count).Item(0)
        Next
        'Find average mark
        barlength(i) = total / maxrows4
        'Make average mark a usable bar length
        barlength(i) = barlength(i) * 30
    Next

    'Create the graph
    If barlength(1) > 0 Then
        rectangle_one = New Rectangle(50, 410 - barlength(1), 50, barlength(1))
    End If
    If barlength(2) > 0 Then
        rectangle_two = New Rectangle(100, 410 - barlength(2), 50, barlength(2))
    End If
    If barlength(3) > 0 Then
        rectangle_three = New Rectangle(150, 410 - barlength(3), 50, barlength(3))
    End If
    If barlength(4) > 0 Then
        rectangle_four = New Rectangle(200, 410 - barlength(4), 50, barlength(4))
    End If
    If barlength(5) > 0 Then
        rectangle_five = New Rectangle(250, 410 - barlength(5), 50, barlength(5))
    End If
    If barlength(6) > 0 Then
        rectangle_six = New Rectangle(300, 410 - barlength(6), 50, barlength(6))
    End If
    If barlength(7) > 0 Then
        rectangle_seven = New Rectangle(350, 410 - barlength(7), 50, barlength(7))
    End If
    If barlength(8) > 0 Then
        rectangle_eight = New Rectangle(400, 410 - barlength(8), 50, barlength(8))
    End If

    draw_options = 1

    Me.Invalidate()
Private Sub TMenu_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Paint
    Dim graphicsObject As Graphics
    graphicsObject = Me.CreateGraphics
    Select Case draw_options
        Case 1
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, rectangle_one)
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, rectangle_two)
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, rectangle_three)
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, rectangle_four)
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, rectangle_five)
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, rectangle_six)
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, rectangle_seven)
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, rectangle_eight)
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen_one, 50, 110, 50, 410)
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen_one, 50, 410, 450, 410)
        Case 0
    End Select
End Sub
```

This is fully capable of displaying the first barchart (for Group1), but when I click on a different group in the combo box it keeps the original graph (from Group1).

I hope I have explained this properly and made it clear what I mean but if not please feel free to ask me to explain again.

Please note: `lstSUsername` is a listbox to contain the usernames of students who are in a particular class.

Comment: I just realised that the problem is my SQL and even when searching on Access itself it is returning all of the results for a particular topics and not taking the username into consideration. I have no idea why this is, anyone know?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out my SQL was incorrect. When I corrected it the code functioned as I wanted it to in terms of updating the graphs when the class was changed.